# volume of sub blocks?

Tags: volume

I am trying to determine the volume of a series of cubes (with nodes of known xyz) that are intersected by a solid. The solid intersecting is a cuboid. 
I have looked into the marching cubes algorithm but that appears to require the nodes to be contain a value prior to processing.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers
Damien